# How do I make it easier on my player in a one-on-one campaign of Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus?

Tags: dnd-5e, one-on-one, roll20, baldurs-gate-descent-into-avernus

So I'm running a new campaign on Roll20, going through the *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus* module that WotC released a few months back.

It's my first time running a campaign in *several* years, so I'm a little rusty. It's also my first time seriously using Roll20 for anything—all my previous campaigns have been in-person tabletop experiences. Any other time that I've used the website, it's been limited to a player role.

My **major** issue is that it's just me and one other person (at the moment). 
He's playing two characters since he wanted to experiment, and I started them off at 3rd level [for gameplay reasons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/dungeons-dragons-discussion/tips-tactics/847-starting-a-5e-game-with-brand-new-players-level-1), but  I'm running into problems with combat. 
I've looked into different solutions, but I'm hoping creating a post will get more specific results.

These are the problems:

- Combat is becoming a slog and slowing down the campaign.
- His characters become easily overwhelmed, even if I:

  - Reduce NPC hitpoints,
  - Reduce number of mobs,
  - Reduce special attacks,
- We're forced to take short/long rests every couple of rooms.
- Just getting through simple encounters becomes tactical nightmares and resource management minigames as he tries to min/max the battle and still maintain momentum.

I'm probably making it sound worse than it is, since we're just starting out, but I can see how this will progress the further into the campaign we go. 
At the moment, his characters out-level the enemies, but that advantage will be gone within the next few sessions, and then it becomes a steep uphill grind. 
This is made worse when we get to locations like Avernus and the environment itself starts **actively** working against player-recovery.

I'm hoping people have some suggestions for me, maybe even ones that are tied to the module itself. 
I've tinkered with things like 'scaring the enemies away' when their BBEG is killed, or the boss is defeated. Allowed skill checks for intimidation to reduce NPC numbers, etc. 
I don't really know other easy, scalable ways to balance CR and not remove the difficulty and fun of combat entirely, but prevent combat from grinding the story to a standstill.

I'm considering creating my own DMPC to help flesh out the roster, but since this is my first time controlling the game in a while, I don't want to overstep or lose focus—things that are all too easy to do when you both run the world, and have a stake in it.

Comment: Btw, the term for playing with one GM and one player is one-on-one, you may want to look around the tag for other advice on the subject (it doesn't necessarily related to you though, but might be useful). I also added that tag and keyword to your title (please check that the title represents what you are trying to ask about.)

Comment: Ooh, and: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Have you rebalanced encounters to adjust for the small party size (freehand, or using the guidelines in the DMG) or used them as written?

Comment: @Someone_Evil I've been running the encounters as written for the most part, but modifying them on a case-by-case basis depending on what the mobs can do. For example, I removed a couple pirates from the Inn encounter at the start, so it was 6 NPCs instead of 8, and then allowed for an intimidation check to scare off the remaining 3 after the player killed their Captain (Player's paladin just 1-shot a pirate using "Thunderous Smite" which knocks back 15 feet. I described it as "ragdolling his corpse across the room into a chair that became a pile of kindling" and it scared the survivors away).

Comment: @Someone_Evil Other times, I've just been improvising things to allow the flow of combat to go a little easier. Declaring an enemy "dead" if they're within ~5 HP to prevent another round from taking too much health from the PCs. Not using the Main Mob's super-brutal multi-attack or special ability every round, even though I _could_, and maybe should if I were being totally honest. Allowing a round of 'surprise' because he described his characters as being "extra cautious" even though the module states "all enemies in this room are fully prepared for combat," etc. That kinda stuff.

Answer (score 5):

## D&D is about Action Economy

The Action Economy is generally how many actions used for what. A Higher CR solo monster can be ganged up on by lower level PCs and just be absolutely demolished because for every turn the monster gets the players get 3 to 5 (depending on party size). Legendary Actions are an attempt to fix this problem for "boss" type monsters, and it works to some degree.

#### Suggestion

Since your player is having a hard time in the action economy I would suggest a few things:

- Give them an items that increase their martial abilities. +1 Sword, Flame Tongue, or a Frostbrand (because I think everything in Avernus is fire immune/resistant). Something to get them dealing a bit more damage on attacks.
- Give them 2 turns in combat (each character). This will allow them to have a game that is closer to the 4 player party D&D is "balanced" around. Maybe have each character take a turn on their initiative and one on initiative-10. This will only help the resource expenditure a minor amount, or it might make the player want to use even more resources, but that's what the first point is for. Up their base damage so that by just using a turn to attack doesn't feel like it's the worst option.
- Give your player something that will allow them to cast Tiny Hut or a similar spell every once in a while. This will let them take a rest uninterrupted and they won't need to worry about what's going on.
- Load up on healing potions. Give your player a good amount of healing potions to help stave off death. This might also alleviate the issue of needing to rest after every combat.

I'm not sure what else would be helpful because I'm not in your situation. If none of these things work combined with the stuff you've already tried maybe looking for a second person to also play 2 characters to bring your party up to 4 might be the best solution.

Generally I wouldn't use a DMPC because the player will be temped to ask that character all the questions about what might be coming up and you'll be put in the awkward situation of either lying about what's next or spoiling it or having a non-answer. If finding a second person is out of the question (or fails) you might have to do this one.

Comment: How would I go about implementing a 2nd attack per round of initiative? I mean, it wouldn't be too challenging at first for the PC's Paladin character, but they gain bonus attacks around 5th level, right? Would that apply to each round? What about their second character, which is a _Monk_. They're already doing 'Flurry of Blows' with 3 attacks each, plus an initial Short Sword opening strike; sometimes even reaction attacks or attack deflections. How would having two action turns per initiative round affect a character like that? I like the Idea a lot, just not sure how to go about it.

Comment: @DigitalDevourer Yeah, a second full turn, so you get another full action, a move, and a bonus action if you can. In this situation I would probably have their once per turn abilities reset every initiative count (so they could use them twice, like Deflect Missiles) It's probably going to make combat take longer as now you've effectively got 4 PCs now, but it'll take some pressure off. You can always adjust for difficulty, but it seems to me that you want more power so that the characters can hold their own just like a party of 4

Answer (score 1):

Usually in this situation I add secondary character who complete player skillset and aiming as character romantic interest at the same time. Only issue is that you need to make sure that:

1. Player character will drive both story and combat. He/She needs to have sense of achievement.
2. It is player that saves secondary character ass when things go wrong not the other way around.

Also you should always have a stake in the story. You are essentially a servant to the players and your job is to make story that is satisfying for them.

Comment: When you mean secondary character, do you mean third (the player in this scenario is already playing two characters)? I also think you can improve this answer by including some advice on how to generally achieve the things they need to make sure of, if you can support such advice of course.

Comment: But, Welcome to RPG.SE to you too! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @TMPlar Yeah, I thought about making myself a player in the game, I just don't know if I **personally** have the focus to run the game and a character without bogging down the action-per-turn. It's not a bad idea though, especially if I run them as NPCs instead of a DMPC. There are a few NPC's in the module that the DM is given the discretion to control or add to the party roster. The module suggests having another PC control them for combat, but I think having _1 player_ control **~ 3-4 characters** would become a circus pretty quickly. I might just use them if I see fit.

Comment: @DigitalDevourer One player managing 3-4 characters is not a whole lot different from the DM managing 6-8 NPCs - NPCs tend to be simpler, but more numerous. In a solo-player campaign, the player is going to need to take on more cognitive load, it's just the nature of the beast.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a couple of combat cohorts that you control. (NPCs) The player can give them tactical advice if he wants to, but otherwise they act as best they can. Perhaps a pious cleric assisting the paladin, together with an acolyte or two using ranged weapons (or sacred flame). They wouldn’t take too much effort to run, their action is to attack whatever the paladin is attacking, if possible.

You should be able to handle this without bogging down combat. Don’t get fancy with the cleric options and spells: you swing a hammer and you can cast healing spells after combat. The end, lol. Your main contribution will be off tanking with good AC and a fail safe vs the paladin going down.

A female cleric works particularly well, and could even create good role playing. As for asking it questions, make it clear she doesn’t know crap, she merely believes in the paladin’s dire need and mission.

Let the player take initiative if he wants more help. Yelling to the cleric ‘cast spirit guardians now!’ is perfectly valid. But don’t do it if he doesn’t suggest it. Basically, play the NPCs as cloistered newbies who have no real battle experience. They have skills and such from training, but no experience using them.

This allows you to give the player help while still making him feel as if he’s the star and the one saving everyone.

At least this approach worked when I last DM’d :)